# excel date format not working mm/dd/yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: excel, date, format

Have a column defined as Date yyyy-mm-dd:
[Date format setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoJnQ.png)
The 2020-04-13 date is the existing data.
I pasted in new data 03/31/2020.
I tried doing format painter to apply the cell with 2020-04-13 to 03/13/2020, but the format would not change.
Also checked the Date format dialogue as show above, both cells show the same setting.
Why is the 03/31/2020 not changing to the desired yyyy-mm-dd format?

BTW, In my windows date format settings, I have:
[Windows date format setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZolh.png)
[image]

Comment: It is because the date you are trying to change is text that looks like a date and not a true date.

Answer (score 0):

@Scott Cramer answered your question but didn't provide a solution. That lies in how you enter the date[s] you want to format.

If you enter a date in a cell that is formatted as `Date` Excel will record a "True date" which is a number that is converted to look like a date by the cell format. If Excel doesn't recognize your entry as a date, even if you do, the entered value will be recorded as a text string, just what you entered, and I'll call it a "fake date". You can see that it doesn't really matter what you enter or what format you set, only what Excel understands.

Excel understands what you have set up in Windows settings. Now, you see that your settings are confusing. The long date is set up as Month, Day, Year whereas the Short date gas it Year, Month, Day. I haven't tried whether this will be an issue of significance because it's unlikely that you will enter a Long date in a cell and ask Excel to recognize it as a true date. Most of the time Short dates will be entered. Based on your settings you should enter "2020-3-13". If you want "31-3-2020" to be recognized as a date when you enter it in a cell you must change the setting to the Month, Day, Year sequence.

Two notes in this regard.

1. In most cases you don't need to enter all four digits of the year. Excel will interpret the last two correctly.
2. The date separators are important. If your set format has dashes Excel won't understand slashes and v.v.

And, finally, you can change the format of a cell containing a date to `General` or `Number` and see the number underlying a true date. You can also try a calculation. If A1 contains a true date then =A1+1 will return a date of the next day.

Comment: So how do I turn my text "mm/dd/yyyy" to a date format yyyy-mm-dd? I tried changing the windows setting to mm/dd/yyyy, and it still will not understand the entered mm/dd/yyyyy as a date.

Comment: That's why I said, "The date separators are important. If your set format has dashes Excel won't understand slashes and v.v." Say, in Windows settings you have a short date like mm/dd/yyyy. That will enable you to enter 3/13/20 in a cell. Then you format that cells as custom date `mmm dd, yyyy` and the display will be "Mar 13, 2020". The Windows setting determines which format will be understood. The cell format determines the display.

Comment: I think you missed where I said  "I tried changing the windows setting to mm/dd/yyyy, and it still will not understand the entered mm/dd/yyyyy as a date".
So both the setting and the actual date entered ARE THE SAME FORMAT.

Comment: In that case your cell format may be `Text`. Note that cell formats can be inherited in several ways. Just make sure that it's either `General` or `Date` in the cell you are testing. Later, once you got it working, a custom date format will also do. The custom format you should set is `yyyy-mm-dd`. I just tried entering "23/7/08" in a cell with that format and it turned out 2008-07-23. The formula `=DATE(RIGHT(A2,4),LEFT(A2,2),MID(A2,4,2))` will turn a text string like "07/23/2008" in A2 into a true date which will display in *Short Date* format or another date format you set.

Answer (score 0):

Press Win+R, type "control international" and Enter.

[image]

In the opened window change default format to English (United States)

[image]

Once you save the setting try converting the dates in the cell by Format Cell options. This has worked for me and I was able to convert the date successfully.